# Set timescale with macro in MS-project?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am trying to record a macro that sets the timescale as I want it to appear, but I get this error when I run it:

Run time error 1100
Method is not accessible in this situation (translated from danish)

Code is:

```
Sub SetTimescale()
' macro to set my timescale back
    TimescaleEdit TierCount:=3, _
    Separator:=True, _
    TopUnits:=0, _
    TopLabel:=0, _
    TopCount:=1, _
    MajorUnits:=2, _
    MajorCount:=1, _
    MajorLabel:=9, _
    MajorUseFY:=True, _
    MinorUnits:=3, _
    MinorLabel:=50, _
    MinorCount:=1, _
    MinorTicks:=True, _
    MinorUseFY:=True, _
    Enlarge:=95
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The macro you provide seems to work fine for me in the Gantt Chart view, but fails with the error message you note when a view without a timescale (e.g. the Calendar view) is selected.

Comment: I get the error most of the time. Can anyone help me with code to select a specific view before initiating the timescale code?

Comment: Use `ViewApply "Gantt Chart"` to switch to the Gantt Chart before running `TimescaleEdit`.